# How to find which UIScreen a given view is being displayed on?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscreen

Using `UIScreen` on iOS is not very common (useful to check scale and traits). `UIScreen.main` makes it easy to access these properties when needed.

Having multiple screens on iOS is definitely less common, but possible with AirPlay and, on iPads with USB-C, external monitors. The list of screen instances is available under `UIScreen.screens`.

Is there an easy way to know, from a given `UIView`, on which screen is it being displayed?

Something like this would be useful:

```
extension UIView {
    var screen: UIScreen {
        // Return screen where the view is being displayed (might be `.main`)
    }
}

extension UIScreen {
    func contains(view: UIView) -> Bool {
        // Return true if `view` is being displayed in this screen instance.
    }
}
```

By being displayed, I mean the view is in the view hierarchy. Alternatively, the same question could be asked for a given view controller, that would also solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If the view is a descendent of a `UIWindow`, get the view's `window` and then get the window's `screen`, like this:

```
extension UIView {
    var screen: UIScreen? {
        window?.screen
    }
}

extension UIScreen {
    func contains(view: UIView) -> Bool {
        view.screen === self
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! For some reason, the documentation of `UIWindow` does not mention the `screen` property ‍♂️ (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow)

Comment: No prob! I see the [screen property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow/1621597-screen) in the docs, but it says it's deprecated... but it doesn't seem marked as deprecated in the actual `UIWindow.h` header, so I don't know what's going on there. ‍♂️Oh wait, actually, it shows the _setter_ as being deprecated, but the getter is not. Interesting...